# regular expression that will extract sentences from text file

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression that will extract sentences from text file. 
example text :

*Consider, for example, the Asian tsunami disaster that happened in the end of 2004. A query to Google News (http://news.google.com) returned more than 80,000 online news articles about this event within one month (Jan.17 through Feb.17, 2005). information by mr. Kahana.*

here's my code :

```
$re = '/(?<=[.!?]|[.!?][\'"])\s+/';
$sentences = preg_split($re, $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

but the last sentence still splitted `information by mr.` and `Kahana.`
how to solve it ? thank you :)

Comment: The problem is, what extra rule do you know that makes the end of a sentence different from a dot followed by a space then an upper case character? The only ones I can think of is making specific exceptions, like adding "mr" specifically to the regex. I don't believe a general solution exists, but I'd like to see one!

Comment: @Iain If  `mr Kahana` is changed become for example `A. Kahana` it will be a new problem..

Comment: I know, so you'll need more exceptions. Like I say, I don't believe there is a general solution, unless you wish to tell me what the difference between punctuation and the end of a sentence is, in a way that a computer can understand, without reference to an exception?

Comment: Well, but a lot of specific exception will be needed - mr. mrs. A. and a lot !! It is not possible and also not a smart way ! But also I don't think A generalize solution would be possible!

Comment: @KaidulIslamSazal: It might be better to do the other way around (white-list instead of a black-list): most sentences ending words have more than 3 characters, if it has 3 or less characters and ends with a period then it may be considered as an abbreviation (unless it exists in the white-list).

Comment: what will be happen when ' tech. ' will come in the middle of senetence ? Also 'Tell me.' - In this sentence the last word has two characters but it is not an abbreviation. There are a lot of critical case like these!

Comment: @AlixAxel: "information by mr." is more than 3 characters

Comment: @KaidulIslamSazal: Then `me` becomes part of the sentences white-list. That was just an idea, IMO there are more possible abbreviations (and most of them use a ending dot) than natural words that can finish sentences.

Comment: @cegfault: I was referring to the last word of course. Any sentence will have more than 3 characters...

Comment: @AlixAxel: Your idea will be applicable but it will require a lot of testing, guessing and enriching the white-list area.It will reduce the error rate but a lot of work will be needed.I think you are pointing something like Artificial Intelligence.

Comment: @KaidulIslamSazal: No, I'm just pointing out a simple, trivial solution that would of course need testing and some resource gathering but nothing of the other world. BTW, in this whole page (so far) these would need to be white-listed: `you`, `one`, `is`, `way`, `me`, `for`, `out`, `so`.

Comment: @AlixAxel: That's a pretty good idea indeed.But I mentioned before - it will need a lot of testing and some resource gathering(mostly depends on the type of text- books, web-article) and will not be 100% error-free.

Comment: @KaidulIslamSazal: In case you're interested: http://www.totallystupid.com/?what=3.

Comment: @KaidulIslamSazal "also not a smart way" - I'm smart enough to know that you can't do this via regular expressions ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You Can't Do this with Regular Expressions**

English as a language does not fit into well-placed formatting rules.  As such, regular expressions are not fit to fulfill the purpose you are seeking out. What you are really looking for is something like a Natural Language Processor.

Unless this is critical to your program, I suggest you instead determine the following things:

- **What is an acceptable level of error?**  Nothing you do will be perfect.  But if it works 80% is that okay? 90%? 99%?  How critical is this to you/your client?
- **Where is the text coming from?** For example, a textbook will most likely be written differently than people's twitter feeds.  You can do research and make exceptions based on what you see in the actual text you are using.
- **What am I doing with the text?** If you are just indexing things like keywords, then it doesn't matter (as much) if you get the sentences split correctly.  It's all about tuning the program to get the appropriate output for this specific purpose.

My recommendation is to use trial and error to get your error rate down as much as possible.  Run your program on a large set of text, and keep adding exceptions until you get an acceptable error rate.  If, however, you need more than a couple dozen rules or so, you will probably just want to rethink the problem.

In short, PHP and Regular Expressions aren't meant for this because English is funky.  So either live with adding exceptions to get a small(er) error rate, or rethink the point altogether.