# Android extract sentences from string text

Tags: java, android, split

I'm working on a recipe application on Android. My recipe source(Rest API) is basically a service that allows users to manually submit recipes to the site, and that's what they archive and return to the client in the form of JSON.

Basically, the "Directions" portion of the JSON just returns one big blob of text as the instructions. It is not formatted excepted for line breaks.

To give you an idea, here's an example of some instructions returned

> Place cast iron skillet in oven and heat oven to 500 degrees. Bring steak(s) to room temperature.
>       Season both sides with salt, pepper, garlic powder, and cayenne pepper. When oven reaches temperature, remove pan and place on range over high heat.
>       Immediately place steak in the middle of hot, dry pan. Cook 30 seconds without moving. Turn with tongs and cook another 30 seconds, then put the pan straight into the oven for 2 minutes. Flip steak and cook for another 2 minutes. (This time is for medium rare steaks. If you prefer medium, add a minute to both of the oven turns.)
>       Remove steak from pan, cover loosely with foil, and rest for 2 minutes. Serve whole or slice thin and fan onto plate.

I need to break this long string of text into sentences so that I display each in a custom view that I've designed.

Does anyone know of any libraries that I can use to accomplish this? I understand that English language detection may be difficult, and after  [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888778/regular-expression-that-will-extract-sentences-from-text-file) I'm learning that this is not really doable with regular expressions, so I'm looking at my options at this point. If anyone knows of anything, please feel free to share! Thanks as usual guys.

Comment: why can't you just split the string by dots? edit: ok now I see. I think that you have to extract a patter and hope it to work well. That description apparently follow the dots patter except for the brakets that you can remove or link to the previous sentece in some way

Comment: @MarioLenci Thanks. I thought about doing that, but it wouldn't really be a foolproof solution. (What if the text contains "Let mean marinate for 2.5 hours"), or something like that? Then I'd seem to run into some trouble haha.

Comment: true. Mine was defenetly a long shot infact. Sorry but I think that you need some serious lenguage detection here.

Comment: how about detecting punctuation(i.e ?!.) + space + number/word with a capital letter as start of a sentence.But I also notice, words in parentheses should probably should not be broken into sentences.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void ParagraphToSentences(){
    String paragraph = "Place cast iron skillet in oven and heat oven to 500 degrees. Bring steak(s) to room temperature. Season both sides with salt, pepper, garlic powder, and cayenne pepper. When oven reaches temperature, remove pan and place on range over high heat. Immediately place steak in the middle of hot, dry pan. Cook 30 seconds without moving. Turn with tongs and cook another 30 seconds, then put the pan straight into the oven for 2 minutes. Flip steak and cook for another 2 minutes. (This time is for medium rare steaks. If you prefer medium, add a minute to both of the oven turns.) Remove steak from pan, cover loosely with foil, and rest for 2 minutes. Serve whole or slice thin and fan onto plate.";
    Pattern sentencePatterns = Pattern.compile("[^.!?\\s][^.!?]*(?:[.!?](?!['\"]?\\s|$)[^.!?]*)*[.!?]?['\"]?(?=\\s|$)", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.COMMENTS);
    Matcher match = sentencePatterns.matcher(paragraph);
    while (match.find()) {
        System.out.println(match.group());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be a solid solution for the text in the format I posted as an example. Wondering how it'll hold up with there formats. Basically I have no control over the text is "structured", it just so happens that this particular set of instructions is formatted in a way that sentences can be separated using (". " ). I will test it and see! :)

Comment: That solution has 2 spaces.